# Changing Switch position

Tags: android

I currently am developing an app that has a profile, and one of the options on the profile is "Status" where the user can basically decide to turn off status and other things like that. I currently have one switch in the Profile Fragment. Here is the code:

```
String Status;
@BindView(R.id.btnAvail)
Switch mySwitch;
@BindView(R.id.statusPenservice)
TextView switchStatus;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_penservice, container, false);
     unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
     mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
         @Override
         public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             cekStatus(isChecked);    
         }
     });
     cekStatus(mySwitch.isChecked());  
     return view;
}

private void cekStatus(boolean checked) {
    if (checked) {status="1";} else {status="0";}
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(
        Request.Method.POST,
        URL.updateStatus,

        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                    if (status.equals("1")) {
                        switchStatus.setText("Active");
                    } else {
                        switchStatus.setText("Not Active");
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (error.getMessage() != null) {
                    VolleyHandler.handleVolleyError(getContext(), error);
                    Log.e("Error Switch", error.getMessage());
                }
            }
    }), {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("id_penservice", new UserSession(getContext()).getIdPenservice());
            map.put("is_ready", status);
            return map;
        }
    };
    MySingleton.getInstance(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(request);
}
```

when I go back to my profile fragment ctivity and go back to this options activity, the state of the switch goes back to its default values of being true, regardless of what the user states. Is there anyway I can fix this? Thank you.

Comment: just tried to re-indent that code ...but it doesn't seem to be valid (you may revert it to the previous version).

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the state in memory, otherwise the UI will come back to the default state.

```
boolean isActive;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        cekStatus(isChecked);

    }
});
cekStatus(mySwitch.isChecked()); 
// personally I would call this method before setting the OnCheckedChangeListener, this way it won't call the web service each time you create the view
...
}

private void cekStatus(boolean checked) {
isActive = checked;
...
@Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
            switchStatus.setText(isActive ? "Active" : "Not Active");
            mySwitch.setChecked(isActive);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to save it in SharedPreferences, online database, internal storage or the external storage (the SD card), the Shared Preferences implementation:

```
private SharedPreferences pref;
```

then load it

```
pref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("myAppPref",MODE_PRIVATE);
```

now when the user check the switch

```
pref.edit().putBoolean("switchChecked",true).commit();
```

if unchecked

```
pref.edit().putBoolean("switchChecked",false).commit();
```

and when the user reopen now the fragment you have to load it from prefs and make some checks before

```
pref.getBoolean("switchChecked",false);
```

**More Explanation**

```
if(pref.getBoolean("switchChecked",false)){
            //turn on switch
}
else{
            //turn off switch
}
```

now if the value is NULL(not found) it will return false(this case is for the first time he opens the profile) , and if the switch is checked it will return true and if it is not false it will return false

**NOTE THAT:** this value will be lost if the user clears the application data , so this is not the perfect method,online database would be the best.

Answer (score 0):

Create a sharedPreference and store the state of the switch

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you inflate the layout, you have to restore the value (on/off) to initialize the switch state.

For that, you have to save the new value of switch state whenever the user flips the switch.

Where you save the value depends on the behavior you want:

- If you want the value to be remembered only for the duration of this activity , you can store in in a static variable for the activity class.
- If you want the value to be remembered only for the duration between app open and app close, you can store in an application level static variable.
- If you want the value to be remembered when user opens app again after closing it, store it in SharedPreferences.  This is the common case.
- If you want the value to be remembered even after uninstall/re-install, store it in shared preferences and set backup features.  (Not guaranteed to work all the time). Other options include external database etc. as others have mentioned.